# grunt mocha no targets found error

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to write tests for a node api using grunt, mocha, and chai. I cannot figure out how to `require` other libraries. I am a beginner to grunt, mocha, chai, and testing in general...

My Gruntfile:

```
// Gruntfile.js
module.exports = function(grunt){
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    // Mocha Test
    mochaTest: {
          test: {
            options: {
              reporter: 'list',
              timeout: 15000
            },
            src: ['test/groupstest.js']
          }
        }
  });

  // Load grunt mocha task
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');
};
```

file structure:

```
├── package.json
├── Gruntfile.js
├── test
│   └── groupstest.js
└── ...
```

groupsheets:

```
'use strict';

var request = require('supertest');
var expect = require("chai").expect;

var app = require('../middleware/express');

describe('Routes', function(){
  describe('/groups - GET', function(){
  it('- should GET users', function(done){
    console.log(request(app).get);
    request(app)
      .get('/groups', function(err, res, body){

        ...

        done();
      });
  });
});
```

I am mimicking the express app in my app.js file. Then I am testing a GET route, but it says the "require" is not defined. Any idea on how I can get around this? I feel like I am really close.

---

UPDATED:
so I enter `grunt mochaTest` to test this. The problem is that it is timing out and I cannot figure out why.

Here is the error:

```
    Routes /groups - GET - should GET users: [Function]
  1) Routes /groups - GET - should GET users

  0 passing (15s)
  1 failing

  1) Routes /groups - GET - should GET users:
     Error: timeout of 15000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.




Warning: Task "mochaTest:test" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Comment: I posted the error. I fixed my error from before. The current two files that I now have in the post are working. The only problem is that `supertest`'s `request.get` isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is relatedh to the way you're using supertest. See code snippet below for an example.

```
it('- should GET users', function(done){
  request(app)
    .get('/groups')
    // you can add supertest expectations here
    .end(function(err, res){

      ...

      done();
    });
});
```